# manage_pages permission

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I wrote an application to manage fanpages. It has a simple form to write a new post and publish it to the fanpage.
Before opening new post's form I check that user gave permission to my application:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
```

But after redirect to Facebook I must give permission to all my pages. Is that possible to give 'manage_pages' permission only to one page? 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It'd be nice if you could, but no, it's all-or-nothing.